# php sort($array) returning 1 instead of sorted array

Tags: php, session

I am trying to sort an array. When I print the sort results to screen it prints `1`. Why does it print `1` instead of the contents of the sorted array?

Here is my code:

```php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST))
{
     $_SESSION['total_elements'];
     $value1 = $_POST["username"];


     if (isset($_SESSION['total_elements']))
     {
         if (!empty($value1))
         {
             array_push($_SESSION['total_elements'], $value1);
         }
     }
}
$a = array();
$a = $_SESSION['total_elements'];
print_r($asceding_order) = sort($a); // printing 1
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php sort returns true on success and false on failure...

Answer (score 44):

**[sort](http://php.net/sort)** just sorts the array, doesn't return it :) It is returning boolean `TRUE` to you which your echo is showing as 1

```
echo $asceding_order= sort($a);   // wrong
```

Right way would be

```
sort($a);
print_r($a);
```

Here is the function prototype for reference

> `bool sort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )`

Comment: still returning 1 the sort function

Answer (score 0):

@Fernando  - instead of using:

```
print_r($asceding_order) = sort($a);
```

or assigning value, just do:

```
$a = $_SESSION['total_elements'];
sort($a);
```

This will sort the array and return it.

Comment: Its is returning 1 because you are printting the returned values by sort method.
All these sorting method in Php return boolean values rather than sorted array.
Now the question is how to get the result than well its simple see EXAMPLE below :

`$arr = array(1,5,7,4,9,2,88);

// **Original Array**
echo "<pre>"
print_r($arr);


**sort($arr);**

// **Sorted Array**

echo "<pre>"
print_r($arr);
`

NOTE : you do not need to store the sorted value in any other variable just use same array name .