# How to sort php array based on value which will not be present in all elements?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am having a php array as follows;

```
$array =Array(
[310] => Array
    (
        [vendorname] => Utsav the vendor
    )
[309] => Array
    (
        [vendorname] => Ashish vendor
        [suggest_order] => 1
    )
[308] => Array
    (
        [vendorname] => praveen rathod vendor
    )
[262] => Array
    (
        [vendorname] => Yash Vendor
        [suggest_order] => 0
    )
[264] => Array
    (
        [vendorname] => amol vendro
        [suggest_order] => 2
    ));
```

And I want to sort it based on suggest_order key so lowest suggest_order key's value should come first and than higher value and in last their comes all remaining elements which don't even have suggest_order key like;

```
$array =Array(
[262] => Array
    (
        [vendorname] => Yash Vendor
        [suggest_order] => 0
    )
[309] => Array
    (
        [vendorname] => Ashish vendor
        [suggest_order] => 1
    )
[264] => Array
    (
        [vendorname] => amol vendro
        [suggest_order] => 2
    )
[310] => Array
    (
        [vendorname] => Utsav the vendor
    )

[308] => Array
    (
        [vendorname] => praveen rathod vendor
    ));
```

I have tried [PHP Sort Array By SubArray Value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2477524/2563139) .

```
function cmp_by_optionNumber($a, $b) {
  return $a["suggest_order"] - $b["suggest_order"];
}
print_r(usort($array, "cmp_by_optionNumber"));
```

And I have also tried 2nd option in above answer,

```
$new_array=usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['suggest_order'] - $b['suggest_order'];
});
print_r($new_array);
```

But I am getting "1" in response; Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can either use null coalesce (??) or check if each side has ['suggest_order'] set and decide how this will affect the test (i.e. what dummy value you want it to have to move it into the right place)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php sort($array) returning 1 instead of sorted array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957927/php-sortarray-returning-1-instead-of-sorted-array)

Comment: from docs `Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure` and if you see it takes the array as reference `bool usort ( array &$array , callable $value_compare_func )` that means your given array will be already sorted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Comment: @AbdullahMalik He linked a multi dimensional sort question in his question and uses the given answer in his code. The problem he describes has nothing to do with multi dimensional sorting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sorting array based on inner-array key-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530631/sorting-array-based-on-inner-array-key-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All sort methods take the array to sort as reference. So you don't have to care about the return value, as the sorting is done in place.

```
function cmp_by_optionNumber($a, $b) {
  return $a["suggest_order"] - $b["suggest_order"];
}
usort($array, "cmp_by_optionNumber");
print_r($array);
```

If you need to do some special handling for suggest_order, you could use `isset` inside the sort function.

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    if (isset($a["suggest_order"]) && isset($b["suggest_order"])) {
        return $a["suggest_order"] - $b["suggest_order"];
    }
    if (isset($a["suggest_order"])) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (isset($b["suggest_order"])) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: What about the problem when an element doesn't have a `"suggest_order"`?

Comment: Thanx @Phillipp but I am getting 0,blank,blank,1,2 this kind of sorted array.

Comment: @MujahedAKAS which code did you tried? yours or my code with the suggestion_order handling?

Comment: this is wrong, you cannot substract suggest orders as one may be 10 and other 1, you need to order by suggest_order, check my answer, it won't sort array at all

Comment: @stetoc of couse you can - the result don't have to be exactly -1, 0 or 1 - it just have to be positive, negative or zero, which is the case, if you just subtract the values

Comment: after thinking for a while it may work, I missthinked it, ik that it has to be > 0 or < 0 or 0 to sort, but I had few cases in my head where it would not order items properly, maybe just my mistake

Comment: If OP is getting the results he says, perhaps swap the -1 and 1 from the dummy return values.  This may push the empty ones to the end.

Answer (score -1):

to compare elements which have 'suggest_order' property with those which doesn't have you can use function like:

```
function cmp_by_optionNumber($a, $b) {
   $lval = $a["suggest_order"]??-1;
   $rval = $b["suggest_order"]??-1;
    return $lval > $rval ? 1 : $rval > $lval ? -1 : 0;
}
```

this will properly order items as you want - by suggest_order key

also you do not want to print result of sort function but original array passed to sort function to see if it's sorted

Comment: While this is an improvement to the code of OP, this does not answer the question in any way.

Comment: works in php 7, in previous versions you need to use `array_key_exists('suggest_order', $array) ? $array['suggest_order'] : -1;`