# PHP - Sorting Associative Array with ksort()

Tags: php, arrays, ksort

I am trying to sort an associative array according to the key

```
$fruit[2999] = 'apple';
$fruit[332] = 'banana';
$fruit[400] = 'pineapple';
$fruit[87] = 'pear';

$fruit = ksort($fruit);

print_r($fruit);
```

But the output is

> 1

How can I sort the array so that the array will be in this order:

```
$fruit[87] = 'pear';
$fruit[332] = 'banana';
$fruit[400] = 'pineapple';
$fruit[2999] = 'apple';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php sort($array) returning 1 instead of sorted array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957927/php-sortarray-returning-1-instead-of-sorted-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put array sort result into array variable

```
$fruit[2999] = 'apple';
$fruit[332] = 'banana';
$fruit[400] = 'pineapple';
$fruit[87] = 'pear';

ksort($fruit);

print_r($fruit);
```

> You got out 1 because ksort return true/false. and you print this
>   value.

Comment: You should mention WHY it came out as 1 (true) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

According to the officaial PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php), the `ksort()` function returns true/false, on success/error. So the correct answer is:

```
$fruit[2999] = 'apple';
$fruit[332] = 'banana';
$fruit[400] = 'pineapple';
$fruit[87] = 'pear';

ksort($fruit);

print_r($fruit);
```